# element string word till special charector in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array like this below

```
const spetialCharector = [
                          "http://www.curryconfigurator.org/cc#Quantity", 
                          "http://purl.org/heals/food/Texture",
                          "http://www.curryconfigurator.org/cc#FoodItem",
                          "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float"
                          "http://purl.org/heals/food/hasIngredient"
                          ]
```

but i want the output like this below

```
const RemoveSpecialCharectorArray =["Quantity" , "Texture" , "FoodItem" "float" , "hasIngredient"]
```

**Anyone can help me out please
if it solved that so much appreciatable**

Comment: That’s the fragment of the URL or, if it doesn’t exist, the last part of the pathname of each URL. `spetialCharector.map((url) => { const url = new `[`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)`(url); return url.hash.slice(1) || url.pathname.split("/").slice(-1)[0]; });` should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = [
          "http://www.curryconfigurator.org/cc#Quantity", 
          "http://purl.org/heals/food/Texture",
          "http://www.curryconfigurator.org/cc#FoodItem",
          "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float",
          "http://purl.org/heals/food/hasIngredient"
          ]
          
let output = input.map((item) => {
  let slashSplit = item.split('/')
  let hashtagSplit = slashSplit[slashSplit.length-1].split('#')
  return hashtagSplit[hashtagSplit.length-1]
  }
 )
  
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Using the URL API would make this a lot safer. This won’t work for `https://example.com/path?param=1#some/fragment`.